# MySQL exercise - Foreign keys and IDs?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

Basically, I'm trying to make MySQL give me the last mark inserted in the table. I'm struggling to understand where's my mistake.
(I omitted on purpose the "insertion" paragraph). As you can figure out by yourself, I'm a newbie here so excuse my bad syntax. I'm trying to work on it and get better.

```
CREATE TABLE SCHOLARS (
  ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  SurnameName TEXT NOT NULL,
  Address TEXT NOT NULL,
  BornDate date,
  Class TEXT NOT NULL,
  Graduated TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE SUBJECTS (
  SubjectID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  SubjectName TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE MARKS (
  ID INTEGER,
  Subject INTEGER,
  TypeofTest TEXT NOT NULL,
  DateofTest date,
  Mark INTEGER NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES SCHOLARS (ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (Subject) REFERENCES SUBJECTS (SubjectID)
);

INSERT INTO SCHOLARS VALUES (0001, 'Margotti Marco', 'ViaSalici', 19890215, '5A', 'YES');
INSERT INTO SCHOLARS VALUES (0002, 'Mazzoli Luca', 'ViaParati', 20010317, '4E', 'YES');
INSERT INTO SCHOLARS VALUES (0003, 'Sarri Lucrezia', 'ViaManozzi', 19900608, '5B', 'YES');
INSERT INTO SCHOLARS VALUES (0004, 'Gotta Alessia', 'ViaNiocara', 19901229, '5A', 'NO');
INSERT INTO SCHOLARS VALUES (0005, 'Ortelli Paolo', 'ViaRamona', 19911208, '3D', 'NO');
INSERT INTO SCHOLARS VALUES (0006, 'Mollica Leo', 'ViaBattisti', 19990506, '5C', 'YES');
INSERT INTO SUBJECTS VALUES (50, 'Science');
INSERT INTO SUBJECTS VALUES (51, 'History');
INSERT INTO SUBJECTS VALUES (52, 'Physics');
INSERT INTO SUBJECTS VALUES (53, 'ComputerScience');
INSERT INTO SUBJECTS VALUES (54, 'Geography');
INSERT INTO SUBJECTS VALUES (55, 'Math');
INSERT INTO MARKS (TypeofTest, DateofTest, Mark) VALUES ('Written', 20021027, 10);
INSERT INTO MARKS (TypeofTest, DateofTest, Mark) VALUES ('Written', 20021027, 9);
INSERT INTO MARKS (TypeofTest, DateofTest, Mark) VALUES ('Oral', 20021029, 3);
INSERT INTO MARKS (TypeofTest, DateofTest, Mark) VALUES ('Written', 20030101, 7);
INSERT INTO MARKS (TypeofTest, DateofTest, Mark) VALUES ('Oral', 20030105, 6);
INSERT INTO MARKS (TypeofTest, DateofTest, Mark) VALUES ('Oral', 20030105, 5);
INSERT INTO MARKS (TypeofTest, DateofTest, Mark) VALUES ('Written', 20030108, 8);
INSERT INTO MARKS (TypeofTest, DateofTest, Mark) VALUES ('Written', 20030112, 5);

SELECT m.Mark
FROM MARKS m, SCHOLARS s
WHERE s.ID = m.ID AND s.ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM MARKS);
```

Comment: Your IDs are not auto-incrementing so how do you define *last*?

Comment: @stu presumably dateoftest..

Comment: You should use explicit joins rather than comma joins and max(dateoftest) in a correlated sub query with a test on dateoftest .  nb it does help if you include the inserts,,nb2 pedants like me prefer consistent identifiers eg scholar vs alumni,,,

Comment: @P.Salmon possibly but I wouldn't presume anything, I have no idea if the data is inserted in chronological order.

Comment: @Stu I'm sorry, I've tried to add some more context. I know it looks terrible but it's one of the first times I ever write in MySQL.

Comment: @P.Salmon I'm sorry, I've tried to add some more context. I know it looks terrible but it's one of the first times I ever write in MySQL.

Comment: It doesn't look terrible but confirmation of last being identified by dateoftest (or not) would be useful.

Comment: If `dateoftest` defines the *last mark* then `select mark from marks order by dateoftest desc limit 1`

Comment: @P.Salmon In order to get the latest mark inserted in the tables, I thought it would be useful to check the biggest ID number (in this case 0006) and get from there the mark. Now that you pointed that out, I'll definitely use DateofTest to retrieve the latest mark, I don't know how I didn't think about that. Thanks

Comment: @Stu Oh alright, thank you

Comment: 'I thought it would be useful to check the biggest ID number'- No id in marks identifies scholar - according to the FK definition.

Comment: AND you are not populating marks with id (scholar)..

Answer (score 0):

If `DateOfTest` defines the "latest" Mark then simply use

```
select mark 
from marks 
order by dateoftest desc 
limit 1
```

If the Data can be inserted out of chronological order and you want to retrieve the last value that was entered, consider adding a `datetime` column with a default value.